# Does Entity Framework 4 Code First have support for identity generators like NHibernate?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

This question, asked a year ago, is similar:
[Does the Entity Framework 4 support generators for id values like NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408994/does-the-entity-framework-4-support-generators-for-id-values-like-nhibernate)

But what I'd like to know is if the code first CTP adds support for identity generation strategies. If not, does anyone know a good extension point in EF to implement something similar?

I'm currently working with model classes which use GUID as the identifier. When inserting using EF they retain their `Guid.Empty` initial values. I know that you can set a default value for the column in the DB to `newid()` but that defeats the purpose of client-side identity generation.

Is Entity Framework just not mature enough to be used in a distributed, disconnected system?

Comment: EntityFramework 4.0 is a big step forward from 1.0, but it's still another half baked Microsoft implementation. The extensibility points a few to none.

Comment: @Jeff, While I appreciate your opinion (mine is similar, I prefer NH), for this particular project I don't have the leeway to use something else.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I was more responding to your question "Is Entity Framework just not mature enough to be used in a distributed, disconnected system?" My take on the answer is: it's mature enough, if you don't mind a half baked implementation in each part of the distributed system.

Comment: One benefit of GUIDs is that the client can assign identifiers rather than waiting until it is persisted to the database.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, Entity framework code-first is still just nice wrapper around EFv4. There are no NHibernate like generators. If you want client side Id generator you will have to override `SaveChanges` in derived `DbContext` and implement your own logic of assigning Ids to new entities.

**Edit:**

Some high level example:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    // Helper for example
    // DO NOT USE IN REAL SCENARIOS!!!
    private static int i = 0; 

    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; private set; }

    public Context()
        : base("connection")
    {
        MyEntities = Set<MyEntity>();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
        // Turn off autogeneration in database
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
                    .Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(HasDatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        // Other mapping
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<MyEntity>()
            .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added))
        {
            // Here you have to add some logic to generate Id
            // I'm using just static field
            entry.Entity.Id = ++i;  
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}
```

Comment: Sounds interesting, any pointers on how to implement it? (how to get the new entities, how to prevent EF from assigning the Ids, etc)

Comment: @Diego: I added some example.

Answer (score 6):

No.

Mine Entity Framework 4.1.10715  installed by NuGet.
maybe you could use attribute

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id {get;set;}
```

please see (The full list of annotations supported in EF 4.1 : CTRL+F in page) [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

```
[Key]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

and then use new GUID ToString

```
Units.Add( new Unit(){Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="123"});
```