# Entity Framework. Column Null or Incrementing Identity

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm looking to update a column in a table from a null state to a unique ID which would represent the row being locked.  Is there a simple means of doing this?

Thanks

Edit for clarification:  This is pretty much what i'm looking for.  After thinking about it for a while i'm pretty much of the opinion it should just be broken off into a separate table and referenced via a foreign key.

```
Pk  | column  | uniqueId
1   | useless | <DBNULL>
2   | random  | <DBNull>
--Update occurs
1   | useless2| 1
2   | random  | <DBNULL>
--Update occurs
1   | useless3| 2
2   | random  | <DBNULL>
--update occurs
1   | useless3| 2
2   | random2 | 3
```

Comment: entities require unique keys/ID-s, and i.e. non null - you can do that with other non-key column.

Comment: The entity has a unique key/id.  I am hoping to have another column represent a locked state.  This column would ideally be unique, and since i can't trust a hash to do this i was hoping for an alternative.

Comment: Can't you just use the primary key value?

Comment: @GertArnold OP needs it to be null up to some point, as I understood.

Comment: @NSGaga - I mean: use the PK value to fill the "lock" column. But I miss the bigger picture here, to be honest.

Comment: @GertArnold Thought about that, i'm thinking at that point might as well just use a bit/boolean as a flag.

Comment: @GertArnold you mean duplicate - null or key ID - that makes sense too actually - but as you just said, that's more of a bit/boolean. So custom Guid maybe safer if some real ID is needed, aside of key or key/identity may not be inconvenient - and bool is a very simple option - unless it has some downsides - I'd vote for that actually. as simple as possible. The OP may just need to 'flag' the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (if I'm getting right what you're after),
your best option is using `Guid` column - and most likely having to custom implement the Guid ID from the EF/C# side - so that you could keep the column 'null' also when wanted.

Closest to what you need is what's described already in this question,

[Does Entity Framework 4 Code First have support for identity generators like NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275306/does-entity-framework-4-code-first-have-support-for-identity-generators-like-nhi)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to represent rows being "locked" or not, the simple means of doing it is to use a bit/boolean column.

There is no need for uniqueness as you already have a Primary Key on the table.