# Generate Guid on Serverside Entity Framework 5?

Tags: entity-framework, guid

I am coming from a nhibernate background and I am wondering how can I generate the Guid automatically on the serer side and not make a round trip to make it on the database side?

In fluent nhibernate it is simple just

```
   Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to generate the key on the server, simply do this in code:

```
public class TestObject 
{
    public TestObject() 
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

If you want the database to generate the key, then use the [DatabaseGenerated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
public class TestObject 
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

If you're after using sequential GUIDs, then there's no easy answer at the moment.  Some examples which get you along the right road:

- [Generating IDs in the SaveChanges method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5277642/163495)
- [Calling your own NewGuid method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6100778/163495)
- [Use a non-EF method to change the default value for the identity field](http://blog.jongallant.com/2013/04/guid-comb-ef-code-first.html#.UYDoc0CkrLk) from `NEWID()` to `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`

Comment: In Nhibernate they have GuidComb what is supposedly better. Does it not matter with with EF? Any advantage between the 2 ways in EF. In nhibernate they don't recommend to do db generated.

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware of the COMB difference.  Updated the answer with some more options.

Comment: Note, if you are generating from the **edmx**, make sure the **Store Generated Column** is set to **Identity** for the column you want GUid to be server generated.

Comment: For EF fluent API see this: http://dailywebtips.blogspot.com/2012/09/entity-framework-5-auto-generated-guid.html

Answer (score 1):

This code does what you need:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public static class SequentialGuidProvider
{
    [DllImport("rpcrt4.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int UuidCreateSequential(out Guid guid);

    private static Guid CreateGuid()
    {
        Guid guid;
        int result = UuidCreateSequential(out guid);
        if (result == 0)
            return guid;
        else
            return Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public static Guid GuidComb(this Nullable<Guid> guid)
    {
        if (!guid.HasValue) guid = SequentialGuidProvider.CreateGuid();
        return guid.Value;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class TestObject
{
    public TestObject()
    {
    }

    private Nullable<Guid> _guid = null;
    public Guid Id
    {
        get
        {
            _guid = _guid.GuidComb();
            return _guid.Value();
        }
        set
        {
            _guid = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestObject testObject1 = new TestObject();
        TestObject testObject2 = new TestObject();
        TestObject testObject3 = new TestObject();
        //simulate EF setting the Id
        testObject3.Id = new Guid("ef2bb608-b3c4-11e2-8d9e-00262df6f594");

        //same object same id
        bool test1 = testObject1.Id == testObject1.Id;
        //different object different id
        bool test2 = testObject1.Id != testObject2.Id;
        //EF loaded object has the expected id
        bool test3 = testObject3.Id.Equals(new Guid("ef2bb608-b3c4-11e2-8d9e-00262df6f594"));
    }
```

Comment: hmm not following this. I make a forloop with a nullable GUID and passed it into the Guidcomb method and it keeps generating the same Guid. So not sure if actually generates new ones.

Comment: @chobo2 I didn't know that the code can't changed the passed in object within the extension method. I've updated the code.

Comment: Hey, when I use your code it seems to change the GUID but if you just make 3 empty objects and check the ID they are all the same.

Comment: @chobo2 they should be almost identical because they are sequential, i.e. different by one byte.

Answer (score -1):

As of EF 6.1.3, database defaults [`newsequentialid()` or `newid()`] may be important when using GUID's as PK's
See [entity framework use a guid as the primary key](http://www.developerhandbook.com/2014/07/13/entity-framework-use-a-guid-as-the-primary-key/).