# Migrations dont add identity atributte to column in EF Core

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have existing model with table in SQL server, also with data. I created with EF Core new model - some bools, ForgeinId, Id with attribute - [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

Next i added migration, i had to add custom SQL beacuse i have to add new rows and connect it to previous table.

First model(allready existing in db):

```
public Guid Id {get; set;}
public virtual Table Table {get; set;} // that is just added so this is included in migration
// some data
```

Second model(just created):

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid tableId {get; set;}
public Guid ForgeinId {get; set;}
public ForgeinTable ForgeinTable {get; set;}
// some data
```

Migration:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
name: "Table",
columns: table => new
{
tableId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
//some data
}
migrationBuilder.Sql("insert into *newTableName* (ForgeinId) select Id from *oldTableName*;");

// adding index
```

Next i got error about insert NULL in tableId column in my new table. So why identity dont work?

**Answer is pretty simple - i have to add**

```
defaultValueSql: "newsequentialid()
```

**to my Id, next delete this attribute from my SQL table.**
**More info here:** [Entity Framework 6 GUID as primary key: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'FileStore'; column does not allow nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081096/entity-framework-6-guid-as-primary-key-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column).

Comment: Where is the attribute [key] ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add migrattion without any custom sql and check if `newTableName` has identity on id column. If it is - try to use `migrationBuilder.Sql(...)` just on end of your `protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)` method in migration.

Comment: Same problem, i added it after CreateIndex. Now i just read that EF atributes - [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)],  work only on .add() update() methods, then they add new id. Is there any way to set identity atribute in SQL table?

Comment: Maybe you can add `DEFAULT newid()` for Id on newTable? Any way you can find answer on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081096/entity-framework-6-guid-as-primary-key-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column

Comment: Okay, that works for me - defaultValueSql: "newsequentialid()", next just delete this attribute from SQL, and thats work.