# Generating Guid by database automatically

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

It regards Entity Framework 6 but maybe it isn’t related to the version.

I have some class which has Guid Id but by inheritance.

```
public partial class TestObject : SomeModel<Guid>
{

        public TestObject()
        {
        }

    .
    .
    .
        public virtual ICollection<TestObject1> TestObject1s { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TestObject2> TestObject1s { get; set; }
}


    public abstract class SomeModel<TKey>
    {
        public TKey Id { get; set; }

    }
```

Right now I would like to change this model to auto generate Id by database.
I’ve changed class TestObject by added

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

to

```
public partial class TestObject : SomeModel<Guid>
{

        public TestObject()
        {
        }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }


    .
    .
    .
        public virtual ICollection<TestObject1> TestObject1s { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TestObject2> TestObject1s { get; set; }
}
```

But after executing command `add-migration test` I got empty implementation

```
public partial class test : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

It means that nothing is going to change.
And of course after executing `update-Database` it didn’t affect the database.

But if I create a completely new class (whose implementation is the same as TestObject). It works and it affects the database.

```
public partial class TestObjectNew : SomeModel<Guid>
{

        public TestObjectNew()
        {
        }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

    .
    .
    .
        public virtual ICollection<TestObject1> TestObject1s { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TestObject2> TestObject1s { get; set; }


}
```

Could someone explain this behavior ?

How can I update my class to get auto generation Id by database ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove `TKey Id` from your base class? (Does the base class even serve a purpose now?)

The property should be marked as a Key as well:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

Then you can specify the default value in your migration. See: [Entity Framework 6 GUID as primary key: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'FileStore'; column does not allow nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081096/entity-framework-6-guid-as-primary-key-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column)