# Overriding the Guid generation for EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, uuid, guid

We are wanting to use application generated GUIDs with EF Core, but are looking to use COMB GUIDs to have them ordered sequentially, instead of relying on the guids being generated by EF Core out of box.

Does anyone know of an easy way to override/extend the default functionality of guid generation for new entities?  I think we can do it on a per-entity basis using the Fluent API, but a global solution would definitely be preferred.

Comment: Have you tried `defaultValueSql`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081096/entity-framework-6-guid-as-primary-key-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column

Comment: @Guvante that would be db generated though, right?  Since we want the Guid before we persist the data, we want application generated.

Comment: Are you using actual `Guid`s as primary keys, or are you keeping the default string key type and looking to generate different GUID values for those strings?

Comment: @madreflection guids as primary keys

Comment: Looking at the documentation the fluent API supports `HasValueGenerator<SequentialGuidValueGenerator>()` which does what you are looking for I think.