# RawSQL and auto-generated keys in EF Core 3.1

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Model with a Guid primary key. I want the Database to generate a key on insert so I added the following annotations:

```
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid employee_id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int employee_number { get; set; }

        //more props...
    }
```

Now I expected that inserts with RawSQL wouldn't expect a primary key, however the folllowing statement doesn't work when executred through `ExecuteSqlRaw`:

```
INSERT INTO employees (employee_number/**, more props*/) 
VALUES (123 /**,more props*/)
```

An error is caused by the DB about a non-nullable primary key. Explicitly inserting some random Guid works, but i figured the DB would take care of this.

Is the Identity annotation wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could miss one step.

When I add migration, ef core will generate a migration file. Then `defaultValueSql: "newsequentialid()"` need to be added here.

[image]

After excuting `Update-Database`, I can insert the record with RawSQL.

[image]

Edit:

Another method to use `HasDefaultValueSql` in DbContext.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
           .Property(b => b.employee_id)
           .HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()");
    }
```

Comment: Why would that be the case? In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081096/entity-framework-6-guid-as-primary-key-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column) thread it is clearly stated that my solution schould work as expected, but the migration is not creating the `newsequentialid()` attribute for the primary key row.

Comment: @Beltway, can you insert the data with RawSql successfully?

Comment: Excuse the late response. Yes I can, but only when manually creating a Guid and passing it explicitly.

Comment: @Beltway, ok, I have understood how it work here. You can refer to the edited answer.

Comment: Is there no way to achieve this through Fluent API or data annotations? I don't want to mess with the auto generated Migrations or tables.

Comment: @Beltway, yes, you can refer to the edited answer.